# How to set dynamic height programmatically to a view?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm creating my own class with inherits from UIView, `class MyView: UIView {`

The idea is to create a view and put some label into it. I'm achieving this by:

```
init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 8.0, y: 104.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16.0, height: 60.0))
    initialize()
}
```

where

```
fileprivate func initialize() {        
    label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16.0, y: 8.0, width: self.frame.width - 32.0, height: self.frame.height - 16.0))
    self.addSubview(label)
}
```

and everything works fine for now.
But now I want to make this custom view height dynamic, so the height of my view will depend on the height(text) of the label in it.

I've tried to add:

```
let constraints = [
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0)]

    label.addConstraints(constraints)
```

and

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 60.0).isActive = true
```

and eventually I get a huge error in logs with:

```
The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint
When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled.
```

Can someone help me with this problem?
I've googled it but could not find anything which would help me to solve my problem.
Maybe I do my layouts wrong.
I will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

the problem as of

```
label.addConstraints(constraints)
```

you add constraints between parent and the label to the label which is incorrect you need to add them to parent

```
self.addConstraints(constraints)
```

Another apple's recommended way is to

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([constraints])
```

Which will handle it for you

---

```
let mmmview = MyView()
mmmview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(mmmview)
let constraints = [
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: mmmview , attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: mmmview , attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: mmmview , attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0)
 ]
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

Comment: thank you! It helped me to avoid the crash but the view did not appear on my screen. I got in logs: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. `

Comment: don't mix frame layout with auto-layout when you add that view ( which contains the label) to it's superview use constraints with top , leading and trailing don't give height , and the label will make the view stretch according to it's content as you currently connect it with top , leading , trailing and bottom

Comment: yes! After removing this line ` label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16.0, y: 8.0, width: self.frame.width - 32.0, height: self.frame.height - 16.0))` the logs are clean now, but when I debug my UILabel, I get `frame = (0 0; 0 0);`

Comment: you need to assign a text so it will stretch according to it

Comment: I have a text inside of it

Comment: print the frame inside**override func layoutSubviews()** make it an instance var so strip **label = UILabel()** out of the function , also give the label text to the init method of the myView so it's knows the content before layouting

Comment: I did what you have suggested and got `frame = (0 0; 280.5 60)` when I print `self`. Is it possible that it stays behind the nav bar or above the view and that's why I do not see it?

Comment: show how you instanitate myview and add it to self.view

Comment: Just adding `let view = MyView()` and set its first frame in `init()` and later in `initialize()`

Comment: as you created the constraints with the label and it's parent , do the same with **view** and it's parent better name it anything else as not to collide with **self.view** of vc with no height constraint only top, leading and trailing

Comment: but my `MyView` is the parent of `label` and does not have any other parents which I could access from my class =/ Sorry, if I got something wrong =/

Comment: here is my code: `https://gist.github.com/orkhanalizade/553c189e45c019bff6fce68e5ea9d050` maybe it will be more helpful for you to recreate my problem

Comment: for sorry not setting on mac now , but remove these lines **self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,self.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 60.0).isActive = true, NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 60.0).isActive = true**
        and try

Comment: it worked! Thank you! But how view automatically stretches, I did not understand this part?

Comment: ah no, the height of the view does not change dynamically =/
it set to 60